# How to bundle asset folder in angular4 app?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am using **Angular4** App with **Webpack**. When I *build* the application using *ng-build --prod*  command, the assets folder is coming in the **dist** folder. But, the **css** & **js** files are not in the bundled or minified form.

I would like to know how to bundle & minify the **js** & **css** files in my assets folder?

Comment: You can use [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) for any specific task...There are different modules in gulp for writing tasks...For example, [gulp-bundle-assets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bundle-assets)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your js and css files in the assets folder are external dependencies.

You can add these in the .angular-cli.json file. They will will be compiled automatically in the scripts.bundle.js for Javscript respectively in the styles.bundle.js for CSS.

Go to .angular-cli.json and add for Javascript:

```
"scripts": [
     "path/to/your/js/file"
],
```

and for CSS files:

```
"styles": [
     "path/to/your/css/file"
],
```

You should not add external dependencies to the assets folder.

Regards

Comment: Can I put my **css** and  **js** folder inside the **assets** folder?

Comment: If you add it to the scripts.bundle.js or styles.bundle.js in Angular you don't have to and I yould not recommend it. Your Javascript and CSS will be bundled by Webpack and these files are included in the index.html

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you. I tried to put my **css** & **js** folder inside the assets folder and I specified the file location in the **script** and **style** block as you said. But, While inspecting, in the source panel of browser, I could see these files not being in the bundled format.

Comment: Can you show me the path you specified to the js and css file in the .angular-cli.json file?

Comment: "styles": [
        "./assets/css/coustom.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "./assets/js/coustom.js"
      ],

Comment: Can you also specify which is the best way to bundle the css and js file while building the application?

Comment: Your questions are too basic. Maybe you should have a look at the documentation of the Angular CLI (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli) first. The CLI is using Webpack as bundler, that means you don't have to bundle something on your own